# Latex table format for springer class

Tags: tables, templates

[image]While using springer latex format, i am having trouble using table in this format that works fine in elsevier and other templates besides including all required packages. So I am unable to wrap text instead getting errors for using `cols` and `pos` and many more.

I have used following in the springer journal latex template

```
\begin{table}[cols=4,pos=h]
    \centering
    %\captionsetup{justification=centering} %ok
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}Lp{0.3\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}@{}}
```

when I try its own provided table format like this

[image]

```
\documentclass{sn-jnl}

    
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}[h]%[pos=h] %cols=4,pos=h
        \begin{center}
            %\captionsetup{justification=centering} %ok
            %\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
            %\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}Lp{0.3\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}@{}}
            \begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
            \toprule
            S.No. & Drawbacks Observed  &  Proposed Solution Protocol when Size $< 32+40 $ &  Proposed Solution protocol when Size $\ge 52+10$ \\ 
            \midrule
            1 & Affect of Area acceptance on high speed vehicles & speed in some order used  high speed placement scheme and observation collected in scenarios & High Speed chase \\
            2 & Affect Of color on low speed vehicles & speed in some order used  high speed placement scheme and observation collected in scenarios &   Low Speed chase    \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

I get my table out of the page width with unwrapped text as seen in attached image.
Any help will be grateful

Answer (score 5):

You need to employ a table environment that allows automatic line breaking in columns 2 and 3. One such environment is the [tabularx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) environment. I would also recommend providing a bit more structure to the header row(s), in order to cut down on repititive information.

[image]

```
\documentclass{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
    
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h] %[pos=h] %cols=4,pos=h
   \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l LLl @{}}
   \toprule
   S.No. 
   & Drawbacks observed
   & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Proposed solution protocols} \\
   \cmidrule(l){3-4}
   & & when size $< 32+40 $ & when size $\ge 52+10$ \\ 
   \midrule
   1 
   & Affect of area acceptance on high speed vehicles 
   & speed in some order used high speed placement scheme 
     and observation collected in scenarios 
   & High Speed chase \\
   \addlinespace
   2 
   & Affect of color on low speed vehicles 
   & speed in some order used high speed placement scheme 
     and observation collected in scenarios 
   & Low Speed chase \\
   \bottomrule
   \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mico. Its working only problem is that '< 32+40' is wrapped (printing on line below)

Comment: @user3696623 - Please clarify what exactly is amiss. For sure, in the answer I posted, there is no line break before `< 32+40`. In what way does your table setup differ from mine?